# Extract numeric part from a string using batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a file name abcd_1234.java. How can i able to extract only the number and store into a variable using batch scripting. The output should come as 1234.

There is no fixed length of the string, if the string is testfile_345.java the output should be 345.

In Unix i find it easy, but in batch scritping i am not getting the proper commands.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to parse the name with "`tokens=2delims=._"`

Comment: If the filename is abc_def_456.java, then how can i achieve this?

Comment: Add `tokens=3 delims=._`. I think that @LotPings way is not so much good.

Comment: Is the numeric part always after a `_` and before the `.`?

Comment: Yes, the numeric part will come always after "_"

Comment: can you give an example with the name of string i.e abc_def_123.java. Thanks

Comment: create that file with `break>abc_def_123.java`, then execute the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the **Last** underscore delimited section of a file name,
use string substitution to replace the underscores with a space and iterate with a simple for.

```
@Echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*_*.java) do (
    set "fname=%%~nA"
    set "fname=!Fname:_= !"
    for %%B in (!fname!) Do set Number=%%B
    Echo number from %%A is !Number!
)
```

Sample output:

```
number from abc__def_123.java is 123
number from abc_123.java is 123
```